# Neo4j import csv / DHCP data controlling duplication

Tags: python, csv, neo4j

i am confused on how to import data

I have a csv from DHCP with _time, hostname, IP_addr

I would like to add any changed IPs as new relationships, but keep the old ip relationships with a status attribute inactive, also think I want to limt to the last 10.

I am not sure the easiest way to do this in cypher, or should I be in python for this complexity

maybe an always add (remove duplicates)/csv import

and a second query to deactivate any old ips (how do I query non current if i have time as an attribute of relationship)

and a third query to remove relationships that if more that 10 previous ips are hanging off it.

any help or thoughts would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like fun. Not sure if every host-ip combination appears only once in a csv or also at later times like an "still-here" update

#### Import Statement

```
LOAD CSV FROM "url" AS row
MERGE (h:Host {name:row.hostname})
MERGE (ip:IP {name:row.IP_addr})
MERGE (h)-[:IP]->(ip) ON CREATE SET rel.created = row._time, rel.status = 1
// optional for pre-existing/previous rels 
ON MATCH SET rel.status = 0
SET rel.updated = row._time;
```

#### Cleanup statement

```
MATCH (h:Host) WHERE size( (h)-[:IP]->() ) > 1
MATCH (h)-[rel:IP]->(:IP)
WITH h,rel ORDER BY rel.updated DESC
WITH h, collect(rel) as rels
// not necessary when the status is set above
FOREACH (r in rels[1..9] | SET r.status=0)
FOREACH (r IN rels[10..-1] | DELETE r)
```

#### When the status is set correctly in the load statement

```
MATCH (h:Host)-[rel:IP {status:0}]->(:IP)
WITH h,rel ORDER BY rel.updated DESC
WITH h, collect(rel) as rels
FOREACH (r IN rels[9..-1] | DELETE r)
```

Comment: Thank you Michael!  very cool.  Cypher has many features I had not seen.  This is a cool language. Thank you again